# How to add a multiple choice system for my gallery filter

Tags: next.js, strapi

I'm working on a fictive project for my webdev formation, and I would need just a little help in fixing my filter system for my gallery. It's pretty straightforward, you click on a category and the gallery displays the images corresponding to the category. Everything (finally) works pretty nicely, the only two problems that keep bugging me are:

-Once a category is checked, I can't uncheck it and have to check another category instead (which automatically unchecks the previous one);
-And as the title of my question suggests, I can only select one category at a time.

I would like the user to be able to check multiple categories in order to display all photos corresponding to the categories selected, thus meaning I would like the user to be able to uncheck a category, and if no categories are checked, then the gallery would display all photos of the api.

Thank you for your help and your research.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import styles from '../styles/style.module.css'

export default function Gallery({ res, res2 }) {
  const [targetCategory, setTargetCategory] = useState("");

  return(
    <main className={`${styles.container} ${styles.gallery}`}>
      {/* NAVBAR */}
      <div className={`${styles.menu}`}>
        <Nav />
      </div>

      {/* GALLERY FILTER - MOBILE COLLAPSIBLE */}
      <div className={`${styles.filter}`}>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <button className="navbar-toggler text-white" 
              type="button" 
              data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
              data-bs-target="#filterContent" 
              aria-controls="filterContent" 
              aria-expanded="false" 
              aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span className="align-self-center">Filtres</span>
              <i className="bi bi-list fs-1"/>
            </button>
          
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="filterContent">
              <form id="img-sort" action="">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  {res2.data.map((category) => (
                    <>
                    <label key={category.id} className={styles.formControl}>
                      <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      name="checkbox"
                      id={category.attributes.name}
                      value={category.attributes.name}
                      checked={targetCategory === category.attributes.name} 
                      onClick={(e) => setTargetCategory(e.target.value)}/>
                      {category.attributes.name}
                    </label>
                    </>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </form>
            </div>

          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* GALLERY CONTENT */}
      <div className={`${styles.pictures_holder}`}>
        <div className={`${styles.pictures}`}>
          {res.data.filter((photo) => photo.attributes.category.data.attributes.name.includes(targetCategory)).map((photo) => (
            <div key={res.id}>
              <img
              src={`http://localhost:1337` + photo.attributes.img.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url} 
              alt={photo.attributes.img.data[0].attributes.formats.small.name}
              />
              <p className="text-white text-center">{photo.attributes.name}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/photos?populate=*").then((res) => res.json());
    const res2 = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/categories?populate=*").then((res2) => res2.json());
    
    return {
      props: { res, res2 }
    };

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first issue, rather than setting the `targetCategory` to the selected category value, you'll want to toggle it. This means checking if it's already set when the input is clicked, and if it is, unset it. For the second issue, you'll need to store all the selected categories states in the state variable `targetCategory`, not just one at the time.

Comment: Could you help me in making the code for it ? I understood what I have to do but I'm struggling setting the states for my targetCategory and making a toggle function :'(